# Problems handling Carriage Returns while writing CSV files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I need to save NSStrings from an array into a .csv file in my documents directory, which is not a problem, but I don't know how to handle the carriage return.. I specify that I want to apply a carriage return every 8 cells and this happens correctly. However when it comes to write the actual CSV file an extra unwanted comma is added after the carriage return! This is the incriminated line:

```
NSString *ArrayConvertedIntoStringFINAL = [FinalStringsArrayWithCarriageReturns componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

How can I tell the compiler not to apply a comma after a carriage return?

Here is the complete code. Thanks guys!

```
//Add a Carriage Return symbol every N objects (every FREQUENCY)
int FREQUENCY = 8;

//Define String WithCarriageReturns
NSMutableArray *FinalStringsArrayWithCarriageReturns = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];

for (int i = 1; i <= [FinalStringsArray count]; i++)
{
    NSString *readValue = [FinalStringsArray objectAtIndex:i-1];
    //Add objects to the final string
    [FinalStringsArrayWithCarriageReturns addObject:readValue];

    if ( (i % FREQUENCY) == 0) //Number is multiple of N
    {
        //Every multiple of N add the Carriage Return symbol
        [FinalStringsArrayWithCarriageReturns addObject:CarriageReturn];
    }
}
NSLog(@"+2+Broken down array strings: %@",FinalStringsArrayWithCarriageReturns);

//PROBLEM! A comma is added after the Carriage Return

//Convert Array into String
NSString *ArrayConvertedIntoStringFINAL = [FinalStringsArrayWithCarriageReturns componentsJoinedByString:@","];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach you have posted results in 2 additional copies of every string. That's a lot of wasted memory. Here's a simpler approach that only requires a single extra copy and no extra arrays:

```
int FREQUENCY = 8;

NSMutableString *csv = [NSMutableString string];

NSUInteger count = FinalStringsArray.count;
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    NSString *readValue = FinalStringsArray[i - 1];

    // TODO - deal with possibility of 'readValue' containing a comma or carriage return
    [csv appendString:readValue];

    if ((i % FREQUENCY) == 0) { //Number is multiple of N
        [csv appendString:CarriageReturn];
    } else {
        [csv appendString:@","];
    }
}
```

Depending on how much data you need to write, it would be even better to write directly to a file instead of the mutable string. This would result in no extra copy of the data and would be faster than writing to the mutable string first.

Comment: Excellent solution. Simpler and more memory efficient than passing through another array as I was doing. Many thanks!

Comment: What is CarriageReturn? is it a string with @"/r/n"?

Comment: @Shady See the question. It's a variable used in the original code. Its value can be whatever you want and may depend on the target OS for the CSV file. BTW - use backslashes, not slashes.

Comment: @rmaddy alright ..i thought it was a defined attribute in obj-c ..thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
`[NSString *ArrayConvertedIntoStringFINAL = 
[[FinalStringsArrayWithCarriageReturns componentsJoinedByString:@","] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:CarriageReturn+@","
withString:CarriageReturn`];

But that would be a *very* dirty solution.

Comment: It returns an error:   Invalid operands to binary expression ('NSString *' and 'NSString *')

Answer (score 0):

i would NOT use the automatic inclusion of ",".

something like this would work:

```
if (i % FREQUENCY > 0) {
  //add cell + comma to string end
} else {
  //add cell + carriage return \r\n
}
```

WORKAROUND UGLY:
IF you need to use current command / program structure (which will place a comma after EVERY field, including the last one), with minimal modifications, the workaround would be to save an intermediate CSV, reopen it and remove every last character (before carriage return \r\n of every line) and then save it to your final CSV.  UGLY!!!